# Protocol with computed properties

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

Is there a specific reason that swift limits us from providing computed properties inside a `protocol` declaration? As we only have the opportunity to set those computed properties as `extension` to the `protocol`.

**Words -> code:**

Why this doesn't work- (what's the logic behind that)

```
protocol GridableGraph {
    
    var yTick: Float { get }
    var yTicksCount: Int { get }
    
    var xTick: Float{ get }
    var xTicksCount: Int { get }

    var maxYValue: Float { return Float(yTicksCount - 1) * yTick }
    var maxXValue: Float { return Float(xTicksCount - 1) * xTick }
}
```

While this does

```
protocol GridableGraph {
    
    var yTick: Float { get }
    var yTicksCount: Int { get }
    
    var xTick: Float{ get }
    var xTicksCount: Int { get }
}

extension GridableGraph{
    var maxYValue: Float { return Float(yTicksCount - 1) * yTick }
    var maxXValue: Float { return Float(xTicksCount - 1) * xTick }
}
```

Comment: Because what goes in `protocol` is `interface` and what goes into extension is **default** `implementation`. If type conforming to protocol decides to use own implementation, default one would be just ignored.

Comment: Relevant SE discussion: https://forums.swift.org/t/default-implementation-in-protocols/15794. Personally I'm against allowing default implementations in the body of protocol declarations, because IMO decls should maintain the same semantics if they're moved from an extension of a type to the type declaration itself. This would be violated with protocols, as such a decl would become a customisation point.

Comment: From [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html). A protocol defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality. 
In addition to specifying requirements that conforming types must implement, you can extend a protocol to implement some of these requirements or to implement additional functionality that conforming types can take advantage of.

Comment: @Hamish great reference. Thank you!

Comment: @user28434 there is a point in your saying, there are some disadvantages using this approach but I can still find it convenient

Answer (score 3):

A protocol is designed to provide an interface (a set of methods and properties), but leaves the implementation to the implementing classes.

When you have an extension to a protocol, the decision was made to have these require an implementation, to not mess up code that is inside a library or framework.

Let's say you want to extend the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol with a method you like. If Swift didn't require an implementation, what happens to all the `UIViewControllers` in `UIKit` that use this protocol? Technically you can call the method, but you'd then get an error because the method doesn't exist.

Swift has solved this problem by requiring an implementation when you extend a protocol. That way you can either not implement it (using the default implementation) or implement it (using the implementation in your class). This is because Apple wanted Swift to be as safe as possible.

**Edit:** You didn't ask why the extension requires a default implementation, you ask why you can not just place the default implementation in your `protocol`, but rather need to place this in an `extension`. I guess it is because Swift likes to keep things consistent, and because they are already allowing default implementations in protocol extensions, they might as well require the default implementations to be there.

Remember, there is nothing wrong with using multiple extensions in the same file, it's even suggested as the preferred way to split code for better overview in the [Ray Wenderlich Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#code-organization).

Comment: What you're saying starting from third paragraph is not related to computed properties as you may choose not to use them- they're just there for help, unlike methods- that you have to implement in swift

Comment: @Niv It's the same for methods as for computed properties.

Comment: Didn't get you, can you please explain me paragraph 3? "Technically you can call the method, but you'd then get an error because the method doesn't exist."

Comment: It's an explanation why the extension needs to have default implementations. I have re-read your question and now understand that this is not your question. I have edited my answer.